# Excel VBA Script to save using a button

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a button that will save an excel spreadsheet as a non-macro xlsx file. I'm new to VBS and was pretty proud that I got a button to add a row at the top and maintain formatting but this save button is driving me bonkers. Also will this script allow the user to choose where they want to save the file? I need that functionality as well. Here's what I've hobbled together scouring the web so far:

```
Sub SaveButton(tempFilePath As String, tempFileName As String)
    Dim Builders_Risk As Workbook
    Dim SaveFormat As Long

    'Remember the users setting
    SaveFormat = Application.DefaultSaveFormat
    'Set it to the 2010 file format
    Application.DefaultSaveFormat = 51

    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Builders_Risk = ActiveWorkbook
    BR_Reporting.CheckCompatibility = False

    'Stops error display at time of file save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With BR_Reporting
        .SaveAs tempFilePath & tempFileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    'Reinstates error displays after save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Set DefaultSaveFormat back to the users setting
    Application.DefaultSaveFormat = SaveFormat
End Sub
```

Comment: Please check Ron De Bruin's site. He has already given an example there

Comment: What's the problem you are having?

Comment: Sorry accidentally added vbsscript tag. So here's the story. I created a button to add a row at the top of my spreadsheet. It works great but if the user goes to save to workbook it pops up with a message saying "other versions of Excel may not be compatible...etc... Would you like to save in another format?" It gives the option of Yes, No or Cancel. I googled all night trying to figure out if there was a way to get rid of this message and the only solution I found was to add a save script that suppresses alerts during save process but I can't get the above script/button to work.